# How to not let users access your API when viewing a site with MERN

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, mern

I have a MERN app and I've deployed it to Heroku.

But when someone tries to view certain pages (where I have routes), they see a json array instead of the page, like this:

```
 [{"_id":"5e4a785440018720b0159cd4","team1":"liverpool","team2":"barca","selection":"barca","odds":"2","stake":"8","bookmaker":"asd","date":"February 17th 2020, 12:26:12 pm","user_id":"5e4a702cb873821fc90cb177","result":"Win","profit":"8","name":"testb","__v":0},
```

And I know it is because I have a get route like this:

```
router.route("/").get((req, res) => {
Bet.find()
    .then(bets => res.json(bets))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
});
```

But how do I still let people view my page instead of the json and still have this route?

This happens because I have backend and frontend, and they access my backend instead of my frontend. Does anyone have a solution here?

Comment: I just stumbled upon this question and one solution that hit me was if you don't have server side rendering, you could create 2 servers. One API and one frontend. Then limit the API server (by IP or endpoint) to only be accessible via the frontend-server. This way the frontend can always talk to the API, but no other server or user will be allowed to talk to the API.

But as i said, just a thought, might not be the best solution.